# Open file in notepad throught Java project

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where when I click on a button it opens a `.txt` file located in the project directory with the `notepad` program. I saw similar questions which used `Runtime` and `ProcessBuilder`, but non of them opened the specified file in the project directory. It is important to use the relative path, because I will show the project on different computers. Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes i have but would be good if you google it and try out something.

Comment: Take a look at [Desktop.edit(File file)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#edit(java.io.File))

Comment: Take a look at Apache Commons Exec - this is a portable library which allows you to run processes how you like.

Comment: Just specify the relative path to notepad.exe as you would on the command line. You need to use a exec() variant where you can specify the "current" directory. This needs to be the dir your file name is relative to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just get the File object and then use some class like the java.awt.Desktop class to open it with the default editor

For example:-

```
File file = new File(fileName);
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
d.edit(file);
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. He wants to open .txt in notepad in the right directory - on some computers, .txt might be mapped to another editor.